# Как создать псевдокод для известной задачи

Tags: c++, c

Мне дали функцию для написания псевдокода. Проблема в том, что я даже не понимаю, как должна работать эта функция. Кто-то должен помочь мне объяснить работу этой функции, пожалуйста.

```
Получить заряд у источника питания. Источник питания отдает все возможное количество заряда

\param[in] delta - запрашиваемое количество заряда

\param[in|out] amountОfСharge - реальное количество заряда у источника питания

\return - отданное количество заряда

int reduceCharge(int delta, int *amountОfСharge)
```

Comment: Источник не может отдать больше чем у него есть. `auto energy = delta < *amount ? delta : *amount;`

Comment: Только нужно будет изменить потом значение `*amount`. Не зря же указатель требует.

Comment: @MaximTimakov пожалуйста объясните, что вы сделали

Comment: @EOF ну как изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее так:

```
int reduceCharge(int delta, int *amountОfСharge)
{
    // result - это отданное количество заряда
    // Если запрашиваемое количество заряда меньше, чем есть у источника питания,
    // то result = delta, иначе отдаем весь заряд источника питания
    int result = (delta < *amountOfCharge) ? delta : *amountOfCharge;

    // Отнимаем у источника питания заряд, который запросили
    *amountOfCharge -= result;

    // Возвращаем результат
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Так работает